# How to replace i18n text of standard control

Tags: sapui5

I have developed a custom app using the control

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.networkgraph.Node%23overview

Now I would like to replace a text from the file

resources/sap/suite/ui/commons/messagebundle_de.properties

I have found the following information but I am not able make it work. Is this possible?

https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/7.52.4/en-US/b8cb649973534f08a6047692f8c6830d.html

Here is what I tried:
[image]

[image]